# ios how to remove duplicates in a nsmutablearray of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I need to merge two nsmutablearrays of dictionaries but my question is there is a way to either remove the duplicate dictionaries ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: What you mean by duplicate dictionaries ?

Comment: I have two arrays of dictionaries. some of the dictionaries inside of the arrays are duplicate and just want unique dictionaries

Comment: If you are looking for removing the dictionaries with same data inside. Then you need to write code for checking each dictionary with the same key. If two dictionary have all the values same, then remove one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, If you don't care about the order, use a NSMutableSet to filter duplicated items:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];
for (id item in arr1)
{
    [set addObject:item];
}

for (id item in arr2)
{
    [set addObject:item];
}
```

Then, you can get a set of unique items.

Comment: How do `NSSet` and `NSMutableSet` determine the uniqueness of an item? Is it just by whether they are pointing to the same memory location, or will it actually test if the items contain identical data?